# form_alter correct coding question

Tags: 6, forms, hooks

```
function MYMODULE_form_views_exposed_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
 if ($form['#id'] == 'views-exposed-form-search-page-1') {
 $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Go';
 $form['text']['#size'] = '100';
  }
}
```

In the code above, which is the correct way:

```
   $form['submit']['#value'] = 'Go';
```

Or

```
   $form['submit']['#value'] = t('Go');
```

And:

```
  $form['text']['#size'] = '100';
```

Or

```
  $form['text']['#size'] = 100;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always wrap all strings in t() so that it can be translated. And always use english for strings in the source code because Drupal assumes that it is english. Even if your site is in a different language (You can translate it afterwards through the UI or create .po files).

The other one doesn't matter. Technically, it's an integer, so without quotes but it will be converted to a string when displayed anyway.